# App immediately crashes

Tags: android

I just started with android development (approximately couple of hours ago), and for some reasone when I try to run my app, it immediately crashes.

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Login"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:id="@+id/uEmail"
        android:background="#b4ffffff"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my log:

```
03-06 17:23:31.723    3578-3578/net.gincher.isrart I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-06 17:23:31.902    3578-3578/net.gincher.isrart I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2830(220KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 41% free, 669KB/1135KB, paused 1.037ms total 7.450ms
03-06 17:23:31.911    3578-3578/net.gincher.isrart I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 116(17KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 61% free, 651KB/1675KB, paused 1.101ms total 7.104ms
03-06 17:23:31.919    3578-3578/net.gincher.isrart I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 61% free, 639KB/1663KB, paused 1.033ms total 7.985ms
03-06 17:23:31.919    3578-3578/net.gincher.isrart I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 82MB allocation
03-06 17:23:31.950    3578-3578/net.gincher.isrart I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20(664B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 61% free, 639KB/1663KB, paused 1.135ms total 29.941ms
03-06 17:23:31.950    3578-3578/net.gincher.isrart E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 86252412 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM"
03-06 17:23:31.950    3578-3578/net.gincher.isrart D/skia﹕ --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
03-06 17:23:31.971    3578-3578/net.gincher.isrart D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-06 17:23:31.971    3578-3578/net.gincher.isrart E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.gincher.isrart, PID: 3578
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.gincher.isrart/net.gincher.isrart.login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at net.gincher.isrart.login.onCreate(login.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at net.gincher.isrart.login.onCreate(login.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 86252412 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at net.gincher.isrart.login.onCreate(login.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I didn't made any changes to the java files yet.

I don't know if it is relevent, but the background is 185KB and the logo is 8KB.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the background image?

Comment: Your app tries to get 87MB ram, but just 63MB left - so it crushes. May you have some big or many images?

Comment: Guys, guys. It's "crashes".

Comment: @Verim the background (bg.jpg) image is 195KB and the logo (logo.png) is another 8 KB.

Comment: Image files are compressed. When you load them in Android, the system has to uncompress them to load them. Their compressed file size is irrelevant. What are the dimensions of the images?

Comment: But when they are displayed they get converted to bitmap

Comment: @VERT9x 1250X1900. If so, how can I have a HD background image?

Comment: (1250x1900x4)/1000=9500KB. You'll have to scale the image down yourself. Have a look through here: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 2):

Your background image is too big. You can estimate how much memory an image needs by using this formula:

```
(width x height x 4) / 1000 = number of Kilobytes needed to render image
```

The (4) is the number of bytes per pixel. In your case:

```
(1250 x 1900 x 4) / 1000 = 9500KB
```

You'll have to scale the image down yourself. Have a look through here: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html